# How to delete a directory "Test.."

Tags: windows-7

While modifying a node script I inadvertently created a directory with files in it called "Test..".

I have tried deleting it from explorer and it just tells me:

> Could not find this item
>   This is no longer located in c:\myparentfolder. Verify the item's location and try again.

But the directory is still there. Couriously if I create another directory called "Test" and then delete "Test.." from explorer, it will delete "Test" and leave "Test..".

I have also tried `rmdir /s /q "Test.."` but it just tells me that

> The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I remove this folder?

Comment: `..` is the magic sign for the previous directory. Perhaps it is searching for a folder named "Test" in the previous directory?

Comment: If I go in and attempt to manually create this directory in File Explorer, it simply removes the `..`, creating a folder named "Test". I can delete this folder properly. I think that this is a bug in Windows that they fixed the wrong way (there were problems with having `..` at the end of folder names, so they simply put a soft restriction against creation of such folders, but didn't consider the case where such a folder already exists, i.e. has been created by bypassing the soft restriction (through your script))

Comment: Have you tried deleting the directory using a node script?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi that solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `chkdsk` on that drive:

   ```
   chkdsk c:
   ```

   (or `d:`, or whatever the drive letter is).

   It may take some time, so be patient. If it's C: drive or it's in use, it may require rebooting.

   After `chkdsk`-ing the folder should be gone.
2. If it's not, you can try to remove it through command line. Click on an empty part of the path bar of parent folder and type `cmd`:

   [image: Screenshot of cmd entered in path bar]

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and type `del test..`, confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. You could try to delete it using a LiveCD distro of Linux. LiveCD means it doesn't have to be installed to use it. Just boot some Linux (for example Ubuntu, which is probably most user-friendly), fire up file manager, navigate to your disk and delete the folder.
4. Last thing I can think of: delete parent folder. It probably won't work on Windows if methods 1 and 2 will fail, but it could on Linux.

Comment: Did you notice that this is a duplicate question, and the author has said that the solution at the proposed target works for him?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi No, I didn't. I have started typing this answer before those comments appeared.

Comment: I always check for duplicates (and check if it needs closure for another reason) before answering a question.